# How do I prepare Murex data so that a AWS Crawler can understand the schema for a table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, mxml, dataformat

I am currently working with a Murex MXML dataset, the AWS Glue Crawler can read the data but I need to make it queryable in AWS Athena.

I have tried many methods, like changing data formats: XML to JSON to CSV, manipulating the format of the JSON, making it JSONL.

Sometimes the crawler will recognise the column names, but not the values of the data.

Murex format we are looking at has changed to appear like so:

```
[
  {
"name.key.key.x":"value1"
"name.key.key.y":"value1"
  }
]
```

or

```
[
 {
   "name.key1.key0":"value"
   "name.key1.key1":"value"
 }
]
```

Is there any process that I can use to convert the data into a format that I can pass to the crawler to generate the table, where each field is a column and the crawler doesn't infer the Murex formatting of the data and not read it as a table.